# Reactive panache: stop fetching bi-directional related entity with Mutiny fetch

Tags: quarkus, mutiny, quarkus-reactive, quarkus-hibernate-reactive

An example of stack overflow when get an object using java quarkus reactive panache:

```
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author extends PanacheEntityBase {
private Long id;
private String authorName;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Book> books;
}

---------
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book extends PanacheEntityBase {
private Long id;
private String bookName;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Author author;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Publisher> publishers;
}

---------
@Table(name = "publisher")
public class Publisher extends PanacheEntityBase {
private Long id;
private String publisherName;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(...)
private Set<Book> books;
}
```

I do `find` an author and got error with LazyInitializationException.

> return find("authorId", id).firstResult()
> .onItem().call(au -> Mutiny.fetch(au.books()));
> Root cause: Bi-directional relationships between authors and publishers can result in an infinite loop of related entities.

Of course, if I map it to a DTO object with no relationships, the problem is solved.
Reffered link: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23757
The problem is that I want to keep working something with Author, not AuthorDTO...

Comment: Please add more details about the error you are getting and how you invoking the Panache methods

Comment: Hi @geoand, 
I've created [git repo](https://github.com/quocthai179/quarkus_reactive/tree/main/service-template) 
Could you help to check it? 
Thanks,

Comment: In my demo, I converted the entity to a VO class to fix the issue. The question is: "How can I reuse the entity without converting it?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project you have multiple associations:

- A bidirectional one-to-many between Author and Book
- A unidirectional many-to-many between  Book and Publisher

The first problem is that you are not telling Jackson that the association between Author and Book is bidirectional, this might result in a [StackOverflow exception](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion). You can solve it using the annotations `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`:

```java
class Author {

    ...

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "author")
    public Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
}

class Book {

    ...
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    public Author author;

}
```

The `LazyInitializationException` happens because you are fetching the `books` association, but not the `publishers` one. Also, in general, you shouldn't use `Mutiny.fetch` to fetch the associations. [The problem with it is that you will end up with a N+1 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping).
You can solve the problem using a HQL query:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class AuthorRepo implements PanacheRepository<Author> {

    public Uni<Author> findAndFetch(Long id) {
        return find( "select a from Author a left join fetch a.books b left join fetch b.publishers where a.id = ?1", id )
                .firstResult();
    }

    ...
}
```

This way you can get everything you need with one query.

I've forked your project and added all the changes needed to make it work quickly in [this commit](https://github.com/DavideD/quarkus_reactive/commit/535741879e7641a7b2a656f69a8a467a02e094b6).

I haven't tested it, but mapping [the association with publishers as a `SUBSELECT` type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetchmode-subselect), should also work well for this scenario.
This way, you just need to fetch the first association (`Mutiny.fetch(book.publishers)`), and all the publishers for each book are going to be fetched.